# How to get data for personal finance software

Tags: curl, web-crawler

For a student project I'd like to write an simple personal finance software. But I have no idea how to get the banking data. How do websites like mint.com and others get the financial data for there services? Do they simply curl the online banking website of the banks and filter the data or is there a general API that banks offert to get banking data? I did some research and found things like the [Electronic Banking Internet Communication Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Banking_Internet_Communication_Standard) but I guess these need autorisation from the bank and are not suited for my usecase. Is there a better way than just manually crawling the websites via curl, etc?

Comment: I *believe* Yodlee does exactly this sort of aggregation - http://yodlee.com/solutions-developer.html

Comment: Had a look around, seems like the only option. No idea if they also support european banks.

Comment: Yea, I believe Mint originally used Yodlee.  When Quicken bought Mint, they switched over to whatever system Quicken uses.